# WPF Combobox with ListBox and static Selected Value

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have `Combobox` (for the dropdown) and there is a `Listbox` in it (for multiple answers). Now i want "Select" as default Value but if i click on a `ListBoxItem`, it shouldn't change. The `ComboBox` should always show "Select".

Comment: What sort of data persistence is required in between choosing a ListBox item? Do you need to keep every item ever selected in memory, or just the latest?

Comment: Every item that is selected, has to be selected until its clicked again. If there is another way, without using a listbox, its fine to. :)

Comment: Please post some sinppet that u have tried

Comment: I didnt worked well, so i deleted it, now i only have the Combobox binded to a List with the Values.

Comment: It was enough it i could just color the items in the combox but i dont know a way to color them if the items are already in the combobox.